# System Verilog - forcing a signal to invert / flip

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is forcing a signal's bit to flip using this method valid ?

1.

```
task
begin
force higher_level.lower_level.a[1] = ~higher_level.lower_level.a[1];
end
```

I've tried this with mixed results at best. Sometimes the bit flips, while sometimes it remains the the same.

However, I've also written a less elegant code with for the same purpose of flipping the bits, which works all the time, as seen below:

2.

```
task
begin
if(higher_level.lower_level.a[1] == 1'b1)
force higher_level.lower_level.a[1] = 1'b0;
else
force higher_level.lower_level.a[1] = 1'b1;
end
```

Is the first code not good way of flipping the bits? Or is there something else I'm missing out?

Where`higher_level.lower_level.a[51:0]` is a 52-bit signal

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that first method won't work. If it did, it would be like a infinite loop oscillator.

The second method requires you to setup a sampling process where you need to decide when to sample `a`.

If a is being driven by some expression, you can force it to be the inverse of that expression.

Comment: Hi dave, just wondering what you mean by sampling process? I've also forgot to mention that this code is within a `task` block so, the problem of infinite loops, wouldn't be an issue as soon as the `task` block ends. The `force` should cease to force the signal once the task ends, if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I meant the `if` statement has to evaluate its branch expression at some point, which is when the task you forgot to mention gets called. The `force` statement sets up a new process that act like a continuous assignment: every time a signal on the RHS changes, the RHS get re-evaluated and an assignemnt is made to to the LHS. That process stays around until another `force` takes it place, or there is a `release`.

Comment: Oh okay, so for the first method if I use `release` at the end of the task, the signal should hold the value until some other value is over written onto signal `a`, or is it that method 1 would never work under any condition and I should only stick to method 2 ?

Comment: How a signal behaves after a `release` depends if the `force` is on a variable or net. I would stick with method 2.

Comment: How does force act differently on a variable and on a net though, isn't force basically just overriding all drivers to the net or variable ?

Comment: With a `release` on a net, the signal goes back to the value it would have had there never been a force, i.e. the resolution of all the active drivers. The value on a variable remains the same after a `release` until there is another procedural assignment to the variable. In SystemVerilog, you might have one continuous assignment to a variable, in which case the variable goes back to what would have been driven by the continuous assignment,

Comment: Thanks a million dave! Been really helpful. However sill wondering why Method 1 worked before but not all the time? I had no `release` at the end of the code, it should have flipped the bit

Comment: For the first method, I don't understand, why it will go into infinite loop, as when the task will be called, it will take the value of the signal at that time, `force` the inverted value and then gets out of the task. So until there is a `release` statement, the inverted value should be forced on that signal. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: A `force` adds a temporary continuous assignment that is **continuous**. That means it continuously evaluates the RHS and drives the result to the LHS. Since this being executed by a discrete event simulator, there is really no such thing as _continuous_ evaluation. So you are at the mercy of the simulator to choose what constitutes as an event to re-evaluate the RHS.